# Floor tile murals, is this proper?

Tags: tile

I am looking for some feedback on a floor tile mural that I recently had installed.

My contractor used some fairly thick grout lines, and I am questioning whether or not this was the proper thing to do for this sort of tile.

After questioning him, he claimed that this is industry standard. And that using a linen color sanded grout would be just fine, and refused to pop the tile back up and re-align it. I tried to search around the ANSI for tile standards and couldn't find anything that talked about this sort of tile.

I did some research and understand the need for at least a 1/32 grout line, but it seems impossible to make this tile look good with the large gaps that he used.

See the photos for more context.

EDIT:

1/8" inch were used, tile is 32"x32"

The question here is, is this a standard practice for a tile of this format? Since this tile is portraying an image, is there a specific standard for that sort of thing?

Thoughts?[image][image]

Comment: I think it looks gorgeous. You did not place anything in the picture for scale, how wide are the gaps?

Comment: It looks fantastic to me. Tile has grout lines. These appear to be 1/4" or  so, based on the tile thickness, which is fairly typical for large tile, and they apparently match those used on the rest of the floor. The question is subjective, and it's a bit silly to expect industrial standards for style. Voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: It seems you created two accounts by accident -- please [merge them](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so that you can gain reputation properly for your posts

Comment: Looks good to me the tiles are aligned, in my opinion darker grouts are better because light colors look dirty with use.  With a light color the area where the tile is dark would look bad. But it is all opinion. But the tile job is one of the best ones I have seen posted on this site.

Comment: When we had some tile installed I asked for the narrowest grout line in the range that the tile manufacturer specified. I held the uninformed opinion that narrower the better, but this is not true. Turns out that it is more difficult to grout the narrower spaces, and discontinuities in elevation are more pronounced. Your job looks perfect and I applaud your installer for refusing to adjust any tiles.

Comment: Assuming they scrape that thinset sticking out before they grout; pay them w/e they want! ;) Also, 32" tiles? This guy is good.... I'd refuse to do that job - I have a reputation to worry about ;)

Answer (score 3):

The pictures show a beautiful job so far.

Grout lines that are too narrow make tiles that have some size variation very obvious. In addition somewhat wider grout lines allow some minor tile misalignment to be accommodated without it sticking out like a big thumb. This includes variation in the tile X&Y dimensions as well as small variations of the laid height of the tile.

I suggest that you are very observant right now as you are forking over good money to get this installed. I would venture to guess that after the installation has completed and you have walked over it a few hundred times that you will be completely past any concerns that you have today.

Answer (score 1):

It's not terrazzo; there will be grout lines. I try to never go less than 1/8", or it *will* crack.

Grout lines less than 1/8" will be smaller than most manufacturer's specifications. You'd probably need epoxy to go that small.

Give me your tile guy's number... someone who will do it right, even if you specifically ask otherwise.

Also, at this point, if you wanted those tiles to be closer, 3/4s of the floor need to be pulled up, and a sliver off of an entire horizontal and vertical row needs to be sliced off; out of the question. And then you'd have a whole bunch of tiles that look funny.

They're the same size as all the rest of the tiles; they go where they go. The other option is to just bring them closer to each other. Then you'd have a border of grout which would look worse.

That's as good as it gets unless you want to drop 10k on a terrazzo job.

[image]

Just wait until it's grouted. It will look *exactly* how it's supposed to look. Which was predetermined by the spacers used on the main tiles. If you're looking to place blame, it's on whomever chose that spacing, and failed to temporarily lay the medallion out with that spacing to verify the client's wishes.